# Debugging Windows application on target computer

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, remote-debugging

A software program we developed randomly comes up with " has stopped working".  It is written in C# .NET project.  This happens at somee point when using the software (some random unexplained point, sometimes 2 minutes into using the program, sometimes 20 minutes into using the program or anything in between) the software randomly comes up with " has stopped working"

There is no 'debug' button to see precisely where the program is failing when the error appears that the program has stopped working.

Is there some sort of debugging utility the customer can install on their computer to shed more light on why appname has stopped working?  Obviously we cant move over our precious project files so as to debug, but there must be some way of finding out what is prompting this error without moving the project files to the target machine?

Please note, we have some 40 people using the program with no issue, it is only 2 of our customers that have this random crashing issue.  With some debugger we could resolve this.

thanks tons!

Comment: you can use VS remote debugger: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Comment: You can use try-catch and add the MessageBox.Show to catch block to display an error message. Best regards,

Comment: There are many ways - log a lot of information, log detailed exceptions, capture minidump on exceptions, install WinDbg+SOS on target machine, remote debugger... You should narrow down path you want to go to allow someone to provide detailed answer.